# How can I monitor and graph this WMI/WQL data?

Tags: windows, monitoring, wmi

How can I graph this data? Looking for a non-cumbersome way to put this data into a graph/webpage.

```
select writeiops from Win32_PerfFormattedData_ISEVirtualDisks_ISEVirtualDisks WHERE NAME = "trax2"
select readiops from Win32_PerfFormattedData_ISEVirtualDisks_ISEVirtualDisks WHERE NAME = "trax2"
select totaliops from Win32_PerfFormattedData_ISEVirtualDisks_ISEVirtualDisks WHERE NAME = "trax2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell's Get-Counter or typeperf.exe to record the counter for some time, save the file as a CSV, then open it with Microsoft Excel and select the data and graph it.

You can create a Data Collector set in Performance Monitor if you can locate those specific counters in Perfmon.

Or use System Center Operations Manager if you want to get fancy.